# Java: How to convert string into given custom format?

Tags: java, string

I want to write a java API which excepts two input parameters. First **inputStr** and second **strFormat**.

```
public String covertString(String inputStr, String strFormat)
{
  // Need logic
}
```

For example,

```
Input Arguments- inputStr: 999999999, strFormat: xxx-xx-xxxx
Output :  999-99-9999

Input Arguments- inputStr: 1112223333, strFormat: (xxx) xxx-xxxx
Output :  (111) 222-3333
```

Please suggest if there are any utilities available? If not, best way to implement this problem?

Comment: what did you try yourself? i'd generally advise using regular expressions or as an easy option substring functionality of java's string class. This site is not about getting the right solution for free it's about getting help when you're stuck with a problem. i don't see where exactly you're stuck here :-)

Comment: Can you paste your code first

Comment: And how do you handle strings which are too short/too long/don't contain numeric chars?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was trying to solve this in a traditional way like  reading strFormat characters 1 by 1, if I find "x", I would write digit from inputStr, else I write the character or white space. But I am just confirming if there is any utility available to address this problem.

Comment: Well, you could use a `Formatter`, too.

Comment: Try the below answer.You can only change the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but assumes that the input string is the correct length etc. If such checks are to be implemented, are left to the OP to implement:

```
public String covertString(String inputStr, String strFormat)
{
    final char[] array = strFormat.toCharArray(); // dups the content
    int inputIndex = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
        if (array[index] == 'x')
            array[index] = inputStr.charAt(inputIndex++);

    return new String(array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is definitely one of the way to solve this kind of problem. I have also got other good/generic solution given by 'JDeveloper' (please see above answers).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;


String inputStr="11122288988";
String strFormat="(###) ###-#####";
public String covertString(String inputStr, String strFormat)
{
    MaskFormatter maskFormatter= new MaskFormatter(strFormat);
    maskFormatter.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
    String finaldata=maskFormatter.valueToString(inputStr) ;
    return finaldata;
}
```

Output:-

```
Input data :- 11122288988
Formatted Data :- (111) 222-88988
```

Comment: This looks great. Let me try. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

you go through strFormat characters 1 by 1, if you meet "x", you write digit from inputStr, else you write the character

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter String strFormat you should implement the ASCII character of (-)and ()
in your logic .

I think this will help :http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-format-string-in-java-printf.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get your ouput with a specific pattern:

```
^(.{3})(.{3})(.{3})$ --> $1-$2-$3 to get 999-999-999 from 999999999
^(.{3})(.{3})(.{3})$ --> ($1) $2-$3 to get (999) 999-999 from 999999999

public String covertString(String inputStr, String strInputPattern, String strOutputPattern)
{
    //strInputPattern could be "^(.{3})(.{3})(.{3})$"
    //strOutputPattern could be "$1-$2-$3"
    return inputStr.replaceAll(strInputPattern, strOutputPattern)
}
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Use string.matches and filter your criteria with regex.

Like this -----

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SocialSecurityNumber {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out
                .println("Input Social security Number  (accepted form 123-45-6789): ");
        String s = input.nextLine();
        if (s.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")) {
            System.out.println("SSN --- valid.");
            break;
        } else
            System.out.println("SSN --- not valid.");
    }

    input.close();
}
```

}